# How to make notepad++ save currently viewed file FIRST?

Tags: notepad++

If you have multiple unsaved files open in Notepad++, and are viewing for example the second/third/forth etc of these files, when you click save you are prompted for a file name as normal, but for the FIRST file, before prompting to save all of the other unsaved files in order.

This is completely unintuitive - I want to save the file that I was looking at when I pressed save!  And ideally not have to save every unsaved file to do so.  Does anyone know of a fix for this?  Seems ridiculous that this is the default behaviour.

Comment: What N++ version are you using? I can't reproduce the behavior you described. In v.6.8, when I press Ctrl+S, saving of current file is offered to me even if there are many unsaved files.

Comment: Hi miroxlav, thanks for trying!  It's version 6.7.9.2.  If I create 3 new files, and then view the second or third one, when I click save it will save the first, then the second, then finally the third.  I know I could just save every file as a workaround, but I often use Notepad++ for temporary files while performing string manipulations etc, and I don't want to have to save these!

Comment: I've just tried again and it seems it doesn't do it every time...  I'll try and find out what conditions cause it to happen and update when (if) I work it out.

Comment: Sure. :) Anyway, when reporting problems, please consider checking these things in *the latest version* of the application. In case of small applications, their latest version si the only thing how they are actually supported. I mean that version 6.7.9.2 is currently 'dead',  no-one will support it by releasing patches of fixes. The only thing that will come will be something like v. 6.8.1 based on v.6.8.  One more thing: when checking for conditions of error, maybe you can also peek into N++ source code to get some clues how *Save* is implemented. :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I had no idea it wasn't the newest version.  Since the plugins prompt to update I assumed the program itself would too!